# is it advisable to use yii framework for jsonrpc only app??

Tags: php, yii, json-rpc

Is it advisable to use yii framework (or any other php framework) for application handling jsonrpc requests only?

I am confused between

1. creating my own file/folder structure with oop, 
   AND
2. using existing yii framework (or any other php framework)

Can anyone suggest, what i should do?

Is there any other php framework available to do same.???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A framework will cut down the amount of development, particularly for something like JSON request handling (which is build into Yii) and thus you would get the project off the ground more quickly and have less code to maintain.

However, for you, there is, of course, the Yii learning curve ... but I reckon it would be worth it in the long run...

How big is your project?

Comment: This is big application that will handle only JSON-RPC (remote procedure call protocol encoded in JSON) requests.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply,  
  
This is big application that will handle only JSON-RPC (remote procedure call protocol encoded in JSON) requests.  

This is different way of handling client requests from server side. Requests will not have controller or action details in url. Server jsonrpc url will be same for all jsonrpc methods. We can use method parameter (JSON content of jsonrpc request) to identify method to call from server.  

Do you think, we can/have to use any framework?  
Is there any option available compared to YII....  
  
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think a framework such as Yii is the way to go.  I'm not that experienced in other frameworks, but certainly with Yii you could easily extend the controller class to handle your JSONrpc requests and route these through to an action.   Extending base classes is one of the many advantages of using a framework ...